# how to set chip select for ds3234

Tags: linux, driver

We are writing an spi driver. How can I set the "chip select pin" for linux ds3234 driver? Name of the functions or the header file that can help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably by addressing that chip with the relevant IO port numbers or physical memory addresses. The motherboard would set the chip select pin appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The chip select pin gets set in the board file that probes the driver, not the driver code itself. For example, if you were writing this SPI driver for the Beagleboard you would edit the board-omap3beagle.c file which is located in /arch/arm/mach-omap2. The edit should include a new struct that contains the modalias of the driver, the bus number and the chip select number. For example:

```
static struct spi_board_info mcspi_board_info[] = {
    // spi 3.0
    {
        .modalias   = "driver1",
        .max_speed_hz   = 5000000, // 5 Mbps
        .bus_num    = 3,
        .chip_select    = 0,    
        .mode = SPI_MODE_0,
    },

    // spi 3.1
    {
        .modalias   = "driver2",
        .max_speed_hz   = 5000000, //  Mbps
        .bus_num    = 3,
        .chip_select    = 1,    
        .mode = SPI_MODE_3,
    },
};
```

And then in the __init function register the driver as follows:

```
spi_register_board_info(mcspi_board_info,ARRAY_SIZE(mcspi_board_info));
```

When you call this register function, the probe function of the driver is called. Check out the doc in /Documentation/spi. If you want to just write a userspace implementation you can use the spidev interface. This is documented in /Documentation/spi also.